# How to calculate bandwidth consumption in pjsip

Tags: bandwidth, pjsip

I see that [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org/) (which uses jain-sip) can display **bandwidth** information when a call is in progress.

How to get **bandwidth** information in pjsip ? Are there any callback or how to calculate it ?

**P/S:** By bandwidth I means the actual bandwidth used by media layer

**Update**
When calling `pjsua_call_dump`, I receive this info. Is this enough to calculate ? If yes, how ?

```
Call time: 00h:00m:06s, 1st res in 1592 ms, conn in 6512ms
    #0 audio PCMU @8kHz, sendrecv, peer=130.148.79.127:33380
       SRTP status: Not active Crypto-suite: (null)
       RX pt=0, last update:00h:00m:01.891s ago
          total 337pkt 53.9KB (67.4KB +IP hdr) @avg=62.5Kbps/78.1Kbps
          pkt loss=2 (0.6%), discrd=0 (0.0%), dup=0 (0.0%), reord=0 (0.0%)
                (msec)    min     avg     max     last    dev
          loss period:  20.000  20.000  20.000  20.000   0.000
          jitter     :   1.125  19.350  27.000  18.875   3.951
       TX pt=0, ptime=20, last update:00h:00m:02.260s ago
          total 344pkt 55.0KB (68.8KB +IP hdr) @avg=63.8Kbps/79.7Kbps
          pkt loss=2 (0.6%), dup=0 (0.0%), reorder=0 (0.0%)
                (msec)    min     avg     max     last    dev 
          loss period:  40.000  40.000  40.000  40.000   0.000
          jitter     :   0.000   7.375  14.750  14.750   7.375
       RTT msec      : 203.000 203.000 203.000 203.000   0.000
```

[image]